# Add "" to mqtt json string

Tags: python, python-2.7, paho

I have a python script thats send mqtt to a mqtt broker. I use paho mqtt.

Script:

```
data = 25.5
self.mqtt_client.publish("domoticz/in", payload=json.dumps({"idx" : 26, "nvalue" : 0, "svalue" : data}), qos=0, retain=False)
```

And my broker want the value in data be formatted like this "25.5", how do I add "" to the JSON string?

Comment: I can't see 25.5 in your code sample anywhere. Where is that supposed to come from?

Comment: Little unclear from me sorry.
25.5 is the value in data

Answer (score 1):

The data is not *«formatted like this "25.5"»*, the data is a *string*. Use `str()` to convert a number to to string.

```
data = 25.5
message = {"idx": 26, "nvalue": 0, "svalue": str(data)}

self.mqtt_client.publish("domoticz/in", payload=json.dumps(message), qos=0, retain=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a backslash to escape characters inside [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html):

```
>>> json.dumps({"idx" : 26, "nvalue" : 0, "svalue" : [1, 2, 3], "formatted_number": '\"25.5\"'})
'{"idx": 26, "nvalue": 0, "svalue": [1, 2, 3], "formatted_number": "\\"25.5\\""}'
>>> print(json.dumps({"idx" : 26, "nvalue" : 0, "svalue" : [1, 2, 3], "formatted_number": '\"25.5\"'}))
{"idx": 26, "nvalue": 0, "svalue": [1, 2, 3], "formatted_number": "\"25.5\""}
```

Since Python also treats `\` as an [escape character](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html), it's doubled in the first output line, but not the second.